# Consulta LIMIT Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

Tengo dos tablas: **escuela**  y **pais**

La tabla **pais** cuenta con los campos *id, nombre*

```
CREATE TABLE Pais(id INT PRIMARY KEY,nombre VARCHAR(100))
id    |nombre    
-----------------
1     |Alemania  
2     |Brasil  
3     |Francia
```

La tabla **escuela** cuenta con los campos *id,nombre, pais y numestudiantes*

```
CREATE TABLE Escuela(id INT PRIMARY KEY,
nombre VARCHAR(100),
pais INT,
numestudiantes, 
FOREIGN KEY(pais) REFERENCES Pais(id))
id    |nombre    |pais    |numestudiantes
-----------------------------------------
1     |escuela1  |1       |50
2     |escuela2  |2       |100
3     |escuela3  |1       |75
4     |escuela4  |1       |85
5     |escuela5  |1       |55
6     |escuela6  |2       |125
7     |escuela7  |1       |80
8     |escuela8  |2       |50
```

Y yo quisiera hacer una consulta en donde me muestre las dos escuelas con mayor numero de estudiantes de cada país, es decir que quede así:

```
escuela   |pais
-----------------------
escuela4  |Alemania
escuela7  |Alemania
escuela6  |Brasil
escuela2  |Brasil
```

Las tablas tienen centenares de datos

Comment: Recuerda que, para preguntar correctamente en [so], debes aportar el código de tus intentos, así como el SQL del dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aquí lo tienes:

```
SELECT escuela,nombre pais FROM (
    SELECT nombre escuela,pais id FROM Escuela JOIN (
        SELECT pais,MAX(numestudiantes) numestudiantes 
          FROM Escuela GROUP BY 1
        UNION
        SELECT pais,MAX(numestudiantes) numestudiantes 
          FROM Escuela WHERE id NOT IN (
            SELECT id FROM Escuela JOIN (
                SELECT pais,MAX(numestudiantes) numestudiantes 
                  FROM Escuela GROUP BY 1
              ) primeros USING(pais,numestudiantes)  
          )
          GROUP BY 1  
      ) todos USING(pais,numestudiantes)  
  ) totales JOIN Pais USING(id)
  ORDER BY pais,escuela;
```

Cómo sólo necesitas las dos primeras escuelas, he calculado las primeras y he vuelto a hacer lo mismo para las segundas, pero eliminando de la selección a las primeras. Si no se ve, pregúntame lo que necesites en los comentarios.

Aporto el dataset en SQL para facilitar las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE Pais(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre VARCHAR(100)
  );
INSERT INTO Pais (nombre)
  VALUES ('Alemania'),('Brasil'),('Francia');

CREATE TABLE Escuela(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  nombre VARCHAR(100),
  pais INT,
  numestudiantes int, 
  FOREIGN KEY(pais) REFERENCES Pais(id)
  );
INSERT INTO Escuela (id,nombre, pais, numestudiantes) VALUES
  (1,'escuela1',1,50),
  (2,'escuela2',2,100),
  (3,'escuela3',1,75),
  (4,'escuela4',1,85),
  (5,'escuela5',1,55),
  (6,'escuela6',2,125),
  (7,'escuela7',1,80),
  (8,'escuela8',2,50);
```